# Syntax help Excel script VB

Tags: vba, excel

I'm checking if cells from A3 and down are not empty and then i want to place a formula to cell E4 and down till i find an empty A cell.

The script i'm trying with is this one:

```
Sub avg()
Dim dat As Variant
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
i = 3

Set rng = Range("A3:A10")
dat = rng
For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
    If dat(i, 1) <> "" Then
        rng(i + 1, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=wwAggregate(""KOSTAS-PC"", Data!R3C1,""Res1000"",'5min REPORT'!R3C1,'5min REPORT'!R4C1,""AVG"","""")"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

My problem is in formula line where i need to dynamicaly change the '5min REPORT'!R3C1 to '5min REPORT'!R3Ci and '5min REPORT'!R4C1 to '5min REPORT'!R3Ci+1.

I tried this using &i but all i'm getting is a string "R3C&i" instead of "R3C3" etc

```
"=wwAggregate(""KOSTAS-PC"", Data!R3C1,""Res1000"",'5min REPORT'!R3C&i,'5min REPORT'!R4C&i+1,""AVG"","""")"
```

I'm just lost with all these ""

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace R3C1 with R3C`i` (i.e. the current value of the counter variable, try

```
For i = LBound(dat, 1) To UBound(dat, 1)
    If dat(i, 1) <> "" Then
        rng(i + 1, 5).FormulaR1C1 = "=wwAggregate(""KOSTAS-PC"", Data!R3C " & i & ",""Res1000"",'5min REPORT'!R3C" & i & ",'5min REPORT'!R4C1,""AVG"","""")"
    End If
Next
```

The syntax highlighting in this post shows quite nicely how strings and variables are different.

I notice that the last cell reference is still to `R4C1`. You may need to adjust that column reference to the `i` variable, too. Hard to tell without context.

Keep in mind that in VBA you need to duplicate a double quote if it is inside a string. If a double quote needs to be at the beginning or end of a string you need to triplicate it. With i = 7 the formula above will return

```
=wwAggregate("KOSTAS-PC", Data!R3C7,"Res1000",'5min REPORT'!R3C7,'5min REPORT'!R4C1,"AVG","")
```

Comment: Thank you. It seems i needed to put spaces between character "&". I was trying without spaces and i was getting syntax error.